# Copy/move semantics documentation of &T/&mut T types itself

Tags: rust

I'm looking for the document about copy/move semantics of reference and mutable reference types.

The following code snippet shows immutable references (`& T`) implement the `Copy` trait and mutable references (`&mut T`) do not.

```
struct T;
fn copyable<U>(_: U) where U: Copy {}

fn main() {
    let a = &T;
    copyable(a);  // OK

    let b = &mut T;
    copyable(b);
    // error: the trait `core::marker::Copy` is not implemented for the type `&mut T`
}
```

But I can't find the description of this behavior. Someone know some (un)official documents? (or am I wrong?)

Comment: Being able to copy a mutable reference would infer that you can have multiple mutable references to the same object at the same time in Rust... when you can't.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Why they behave is understandable, and I'm looking for some documented resources.

Comment: See this issue about rustdoc not showing `Copy` impls for builtin types: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25893

Comment: The [documentation for Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) mentions `&mut T` not being `Copy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust's `std::marker::Copy` trait reference says (thanks to [@Chris Emerson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4529124/chris-emerson)):

> [When can my type not be Copy?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-can-my-type-not-be-copy)
>   Some types can't be copied safely. For example, copying `&mut T` would create an aliased mutable reference, and copying `String` would result in two attempts to free the same buffer.
>   [...]

Comment: This link became [When can't my type be Copy?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-cant-my-type-be-copy).

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to your code, you can always ask the compiler to tell you if a type can be copied, even without being able to construct that type:

```
fn is_this_type_copy<T: Copy>() {}

fn main() {
    is_this_type_copy::<&u8>();
}
```

If a type does **not** implement `Copy`, the compiler will produce an error.

You can extend this to ask the question for *every* reference to a type. Your existing code only shows that an immutable reference to a *specific* type implements `Copy`:

```
fn is_every_reference_copy<T>() {
    is_this_copy::<&T>()
}
```

Doing the same thing for `&mut T`:

```
fn is_every_mut_reference_copy<T>() {
    is_this_copy::<&mut T>()
}
```

Produces the same error you saw:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut T: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     is_this_copy::<&mut T>()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `&mut T`
  |
  = note: required by `is_this_copy`
```

---

We've already seen why `&mut T` cannot be copied, but why can `&T` be copied? In a way, that's kind of the *entire point* of a reference. A reference is a way of cheaply sharing data. Instead of needing to clone (potentially expensively) something to give to multiple things, we can simply give each thing a lightweight reference to the original thing. If references couldn't be copied, they wouldn't have nearly the same amount of value.