# Seeming contradictory borrowing scenarios in Rust

Tags: scope, rust

This first Rust program won't compile because `b` is dropped before its reference `r`, which makes sense:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "a";
    let v;
    {
        let b = "b";
        v = &b;
    }
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

In this second Rust program, a reference to `b` is retrieved via a function, and all of the sudden there's no issue:

```
fn getRef(b: &str) -> &str {
    b
}

fn main() {
    let a = "a";
    let v;
    {
        let b = "b";
        v = getRef(&b);
    }
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

The thing is, `v` is still a reference to `b`, and `b` is out of scope for the `println!()`.

Why are these two different?

Comment: I changed it for a better second example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they aren't doing the same thing.

If you [print the type of the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747136/how-do-i-print-the-type-of-a-variable-in-rust), you'll see that in the first example, `v` is of type `&&str`, specifically `& &'static str`. In the second example, `v` is of type `&str`, specifically `&'static str`.

In the first example, you have a reference to a local value, which indeed goes out of scope.

In the second example, although you take a reference to `b`, producing a `&&str`, you then call a function that expects a `&str`. [`Deref` coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html) kicks in and automatically dereferences the value.

Thus the second example is equivalent to

```
fn main() {
    let a = "a";
    let v;
    {
        let b = "b";
        v = b;
    }
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

That is, you are making a copy of an immutable reference to a string that will live the entire life of the program.

Comment: In the second example, why isn't the type of `&b` `&&'static str`?

Comment: Weird - so Rust automatically dereferences arguments as many times as is necessary? `getRef(&&&&&&&&&&&b)` compiles just fine.

Comment: @MichaelHewson [dereferences and then references once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423). And not just arguments, but [return values and variable assignments too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43036307/155423).

Comment: @MichaelHewson: It's a bit weird indeed; very useful for smart pointers though, which is the primary usecase of `Deref`.

Comment: So `a` and `b` have the same lifetime. And you could just pass b in directly to getRef().

Comment: ... without losing ownership in the process?

Comment: @AaronF yes, because [immutable references implement `Copy`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37381212/155423).