# Are reference values copied in Rust?

Tags: reference, rust

Am I correct to assume that, for the following code

```
let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
let b = &a;
let c = b;
```

The memory presentation will be something like this, assuming the value of `b` is "B"?

```
  _            _
b|B|         c|B|
  |____________|
  |
  V
  _________
a|_________|
```

I'm only asking about immutable references, as there can be only 1 mutable reference, as far as I remember.

Comment: See also [Do all primitive types implement the Copy trait?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41413336/155423)

Comment: See also [Copy/move semantics documentation of &T/&mut T types itself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37381212/155423)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is correct.

In Rust terms, `&T` is `Copy`, which means that it can be copied bitwise without transferring ownership.

Comment: But &mut T is moved, right?

Comment: @Exander: Yes, this is necessary to ensure **Aliasing XOR Mutability**.

Comment: Thoughts on marking this as a duplicate to the second comment I added on OP?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Does look like a dupe indeed, I'll leave you the honour since you hunted it down.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I agree, and thank you all for your explanations.

Comment: Are lifetimes copied as well when a reference is copied? Or can the copy have an different lifetime compared to the original reference?

Comment: @raj: Excellent question. The lifetime is part of the _type_ and therefore is copied too. However when calling a function, Rust may "align" lifetimes, possibly by re-borrowing, so it may look like the lifetime changed which may be where your confusion stems from.